¿Cuál es la mejor forma de manejar autenticación con JWT en una aplicación MERN? ¿localStorage o Cookies?
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación MERN y estoy buscando la mejor práctica para manejar la autenticación con JWT. He leído que almacenar el JWT en localStorage no es seguro por posibles ataques XSS, mientras que en muchos lugares sugieren manejarlo en Cookies HTTP-only.
Actualmente, el flujo de autenticación que tengo pensado es:

Access Token de corta duración y Refresh Token de larga duración.
Access Token almacenado en el estado de la aplicación (por ejemplo, en el contexto de autenticación de React) y Refresh Token en una cookie HTTP-only.
Al expirar el Access Token, se envía una solicitud para refrescarlo usando el Refresh Token en la cookie.

Mis dudas son:

¿Es esta la mejor práctica para manejar JWT en una aplicación MERN?

De ser así, ¿cómo debería estructurar la lógica en el frontend? He notado que, al guardar el Access Token en el estado de la aplicación, el token solo sería accesible desde componentes funcionales, lo cual me hace considerar el uso de Custom Hooks para manejar la autenticación y enviar el Access Token en cada solicitud.

¿Debería utilizar Custom Hooks para las funciones de autenticación, en lugar de un servicio de autenticación separado, para manejar el acceso al token en el estado?


Agradezco cualquier consejo sobre la mejor forma de estructurar esta lógica y recomendaciones para asegurar la aplicación sin comprometer la modularidad del código.

El localstorage no es inseguro per se, tu app debe ser vulnerable a ataques XSS para que lo sea. Pero ciertamente una cookie HttpOnly es mejor. Luego la cookie se envía automáticamente al servidor en cada solicitud HTTP. Dicho esto, no entiendo tus dudas
